# Calculating $\mathbb E$ and $\mathbb V$ of a random variable.

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

$\begin{pmatrix}&&&&\mathrm{payout}\\\mathrm{age,sex}&&1&&2&&4\\68, female&&1&&-&&1\\67,male&&-&&2&&-\end{pmatrix}$

I don't know how to properly format matrices, so let's explain it:

We got two $68$ year old females. If female_1 dies we have to  pay $1$. If female_2 dies we have to pay $4$.

We got two $67$ year old males. If one of them dies we have to pay $2$. If both die we have to pay $2+ 2=4$.

(If noone dies we don't have to pay anything)

> Let $S$ be our total payoff. I want to calculate $\mathbb E(P)$ and $\mathbb V(P)$.

$q_{68,f}$ and $q_{67m,}$ are the probabilities that a 68 year old female (67 year old male respectively) dies.

So $\mathbb E(S)=q_{68,f}\cdot 1+q_{68,f}\cdot 4+q_{67,m}2+q_{67,m}2=q_{68,f}\cdot 5+q_{67,m}4$

For  $\mathbb E(S^2)$ which of these numbers do I have to square? 1, 4, 2, 2 or 5, 4?

Or do I have to do it like this: $\mathbb E(S)=\sum_{k=0}^9k\cdot\mathbb P(S=k)$ and $\mathbb E(S^2)=\sum_{k=0}^9k^2\cdot\mathbb P(S=k)$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the deaths are independent, you have

$$\mathbb E(S^2)=q_{68,f}\cdot 1^2+q_{68,f}\cdot 4^2+q_{67,m}2^2+q_{67,m}2^2=q_{68,f}\cdot 17+q_{67,m}8$$